# regex - get new path string from old path string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to run a shell script in linux and want to turn this:

```
/path/to/(\w+)/b/c
```

into

```
/path/to/(\w+)/b/(\w+)\.txt
```

(where \w+ should remain the same as given in input).

I keep getting 'No match found'.

Comment: Regex of which programming language are you using? Some don't parse `\w` by default.
Also `.` in regex means match any you should escape it as `\.` if you want to match a dot
`/path/to/(\w+)/b/(\w+)\.txt`

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the string you are matching your regular expression against?

Comment: Please add the full script that you have, this will help answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the capturing group and then use that in your substitution.

```
\/r\/path\/to\/(\w+).*
```

Test string

```
/r/path/to/teststring/b/c
```

Substitution

```
/path/to/\1/b/\1\.txt
```

Result

```
/path/to/teststring/b/teststring.txt
```

I have created a regex101 playground for you here

https://regex101.com/r/R0O3OK/1

Comment: Dear Downvoter, please enlighten us with your knowledge why this is not the solution.